# Archimesh is missing

Tags: add-on, archimesh-add-on

I downloaded Blender from the official website two days ago to make a VR project, and I saw someone on YouTube using Archimesh add-on to build a room and objects. I pressed <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> and tried to find Archimesh add-ton to activate it. But it's not there. I even tried to install it manually from GitHub, but still doesn't appear. Any suggestions?

Comment: From his repo: *** NOTICE *** Archimesh is now part of Blender official releases, so this Git repository is only for reference. If you want download last versions or report a bug, please uses Blender website.

Comment: @WhatAMesh he said he used an official website download...

Comment: I have this blender-2.79b-linux-glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2 (md5sum 099555c6c8cb16bfcc0745dd303d692c) and "archimesh" is there: are you sure to have "community" addons setting enabled, just under the search box?

Answer (score 1):

**Archimesh in Blender Version2.79**

Go to *File > User Preferences* menu. A new dialogue will appear showing User Preferences.

Click on *Add-ons*, in search and type **Arch** , below the search go to *Supported Level* and click *Community*.

Wooo, finally you will see Add Mesh: Archimesh on the right panel.

[image]